# Download/Save attachment using Jboss DMR

Tags: java, jboss, jboss-cli

I have a Jboss CLI command which I'm trying to implement in Java using the DMR library. The step involves downloading an attachment (display/save), however there's no documentation available anywhere. Any help is appreciated.

CLI command I'm trying to convert to DMR:

```
attachment display --operation=/deployment=app.war:read-content(path=META-INF/MANIFEST.MF)
```

Below is my operation object, however there's no way to provide command to display/save attachment

```
ModelNode request = new ModelNode();
request.get(ClientConstants.OP_ADDR).add(ClientConstants.DEPLOYMENT, "app.war");
request.get(ClientConstants.OP).set(ClientConstants.READ_CONTENT_OPERATION);
request.get(ClientConstants.PATH).set("META-INF/MANIFEST.MF");
```

All that this DMR operation produces is

```
{
    "outcome" => "success",
    "result" => {"uuid" => "1f45b2bf-8402-4b46-a721-3e3f23db5d80"},
    "response-headers" => {"attached-streams" => [{
        "uuid" => "1f45b2bf-8402-4b46-a721-3e3f23db5d80",
        "mime-type" => "text/plain"
    }]}
}
```

Is there a way to either edit the operation or to use the uuid returned in the operation to download the attachment from the stream?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see any clear documentation on this either. However what you need to use is the `OperationResponse` to get the stream. Here's an example.

```java
public class ReadContent {

    public static void main(final String[] args) throws Exception {

        try (ModelControllerClient client = ModelControllerClient.Factory.create("localhost", 9990)) {
            try (
                    StreamEntry entry = readContent(client, "kitchensink.war", "META-INF/MANIFEST.MF");
                    InputStream in = entry.getStream();
            ) {
                int len;
                final byte[] buffer = new byte[256];
                while ((len = in.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                    System.out.write(buffer, 0, len);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private static StreamEntry readContent(final ModelControllerClient client, final String deploymentName, final String path) throws IOException {
        final ModelNode address = Operations.createAddress("deployment", deploymentName);
        final ModelNode op = Operations.createOperation(ClientConstants.READ_CONTENT_OPERATION, address);
        op.get(ClientConstants.PATH).set(path);

        // Execute the operation
        final OperationResponse response = client.executeOperation(Operation.Factory.create(op), OperationMessageHandler.logging);

        // Get the response node to evaluate the outcome
        final ModelNode outcome = response.getResponseNode();
        if (Operations.isSuccessfulOutcome(outcome)) {
            // Read the result and get the UUID the stream is attached to
            final String uuid = Operations.readResult(outcome).get(ClientConstants.UUID).asString();
            return response.getInputStream(uuid);
        }

        // The operation has failed, raise and exception with the failure description
        throw new RuntimeException("Failed to read the content: " + Operations.getFailureDescription(outcome).asString());
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you James, this worked beautifully. I had gotten to the point of getting the UUID, and also StreamEntry, but couldnt tie those two together. Using OperationResponse and then response.getInputStream(uuid) was the magic. Much appreciated.